# Why aren't new files in my project copied to each target in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I've made a copy of a target in Xcode. When I create a source code file, it is added to the original target's "Compile Sources" Build Phase, but not the copy's Build Phase. Why, and how can I ensure that each target sees the new source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new file (or add a new file) the dialog box has a section at the bottom for target membership. Simply check the boxes for all targets that you wish the file to be compiled into.

If you have an already existing file you wish to add to a target, you can do so in either the <kbd>Compile Sources</kbd> section of the <kbd>Build Phases</kbd> view, or the <kbd>Utilities</kbd>  sidebar (right sidebar) when a source file is selected.

Both methods are illustrated by this screenshot:
[image]